# Why is Luffy's smile so different in his latest wanted poster?

Tags: one-piece, manga-production

I don't remember which chapter this started in, but I've noticed that his smile is not as wide as usual.
It's very different from his wide, rubber-skinned smile. Now it looks more like a girl's smile in One Piece.

I know it doesn't matter much but could there be another artist besides Oda who is working on One Piece? Or could this hint to something related to a change in his stretchiness or something?

I've also noticed that he looks younger than pre-timeskip. Both of these could simply be a change in Oda's art style though.

[image]

The last poster was shown in the manga too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new wanted poster image is also seen in the most recent (chapter 903) wanted poster.

If you are specifically asking for why his smile would become less wide, it could be a hint of him maturing, from the little kid which wants to take on the world to the grown man who... still wants to take on the world, but recognizes that he has limitation.

Of course, this is just speculation and I doubt this will revealed in future work. But maybe Oda gives an interview about this some day...

Answer (score 1):

I actually think it's simply the evolution of his art style. Your theory is tight and even though Oda has been very careful with his little hints, I don't believe that it is actually the case. Truth be told, I have not noticed any changes in his smile even in the latest chapters. As cheerful as always